# A way to remotely run my PHP file

Tags: php, macos

I have created a `.php` file, which I can run from my Mac and it works great.
This `.php` file needs an SSL connection,and it also has another file it uses (certificates `.mem` for `APNS`) .

I would like to be able to remotely run this file from any browser, in my Mac, so i will get some IP address, that when opened in a browser, the `.php` will be executed.

I was trying `port forwarding`, without any success, and I am looking for other services that do that.

Comment: check this http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/php/44933-how-run-php-script-residing-remote-server.html

Comment: and using Apache server with https protocol doesn't solve your problem ?

Comment: "I would like to be able to remotely run this file from any browser, in my Mac" - do you mean that the browser could be on any (remote) computer on the web?